# assign value to last multidimensional array

Tags: php

i just want to assign array value to my last array inside multidimensional array.
Here is my array

```
Array (
[college] => Array (
    [student] => Array (
        [contact] => Array ()
    )
    [parents] => Array (
         [contact] => Array ()
    ) 
) 
[school] => Array (
    [parents] => Array (
        [contact] => Array ()
    )
    [student] => Array (
         [contact] => Array ()
    ) 
    [data] => Array (
         [contact] => Array()
    )
))
```

Things are that every things is dynamic some time it could be simple array or might be multidimensional array.
every key and value are dynamic
i want to assign array value to last array eg.
i want something like that.

```
$assignArray = array('primary_number'=>123,'main_number'=>123);
Array (
[college] => Array (
    [student] => Array (
        [contact] => Array ('primary_number'=>123,'main_number'=>123)
    )
    [parents] => Array (
         [contact] => Array ('primary_number'=>123,'main_number'=>123)
    ) 
) 
[school] => Array (
    [parents] => Array (
        [contact] => Array ('primary_number'=>123,'main_number'=>123)
    )
    [student] => Array (
         [contact] => Array ('primary_number'=>123,'main_number'=>123)
    ) 
    [data] => Array (
         [contact] => Array('primary_number'=>123,'main_number'=>123)
    )
))
```

can any one solve it? 
any help will appreciate..

Comment: You mean you want to assign it to all the most deeply nested arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive procedure:

```
function replace_leaf_arrays(&$array, $replacement) {
    foreach ($array as &$val) {
        if (empty($val)) {
            $val = $replacement;
        } else {
            replace_leaf_arrays($val, $replacement);
        }
    }
}

replace_leaf_arrays($main_array, $assignArray);
```